# how to use rtl mode in react-native-reanimated-carousel

Tags: javascript, react-native

i'm trying to use this [react-native-reanimated-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-reanimated-carousel) in my project, i need the carousel direction to be rtl but i just can't achieve that, it mentions on the npm page that rtl mode is supported, how can i achieve it?

i just want a [normal horizontal carousel](https://github.com/dohooo/react-native-reanimated-carousel/blob/main/exampleExpo/src/normal/index.tsx) with direction as rtl

i also tried the modeConfig options object where i changed the snapDirection but that didn't also work.

here is my code

```
function PagesContainer({ currentPageNumber, setCurrentPageNumber }) {
    const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    let pageComponents = [<Comp />, <Comp />, <Comp />, <Comp />]
    }
    return (<Carousel
        width={width}
        height={width * 2}
        autoPlay={false}
        loop={false}
        data={pageComponents}
        defaultIndex={currentPageNumber == 1 ? 0 : 1}
        modeConfig={{ snapDirection: 'right' }}
        renderItem={({ index }) => {
            return pageComponents[index];
        }}
    />)
}
```

Comment: Try adding `{transform: [{scaleX: -1}]}` to the container. I think you can also use the `autoPlayReverse` prop too

Comment: Have you checked the docs, or the GitHub repo? [#238](https://github.com/dohooo/react-native-reanimated-carousel/issues/238#issuecomment-1311265888) seems to answer your question.

Comment: docs say nothing except that rtl mode is supported without any further details. that github thread introduces a hacky solution that solves nothing.

Comment: The solution works though. Since there's an open issue for it, you can submit an improvement as a PR. SO probably isn't the best place to get help with a very specific library - either the discussions tab of the repo, or one of the existing open issues on the topic would be better.